# Generate specific time in wiremock

Tags: java, helper, wiremock, wiremock-standalone

In Wiremock, I need to generate specific time. I need a difference from 0-59 minute from Wiremock in yyyyMMdd format. Is this possible?

I tried `{{now offset = '83160 seconds' format='yyyyMMdd'}}`, but now able to get desired result.

Can you any one suggest how we can achieve this requirement?

Comment: When you say you want a difference of 0-59 minutes, but the format should only be in whole days, do you mean yoy want next day if time is > 23:00? Can you show some examples?

Comment: @RogerLindsjö i give you an example: i don't no its possible or not, but i need to to generate time difference between 0-59 min for same day with this format

Comment: I don't see any example, and I don't understand how you want to have a difference of 0-59 minutes of the same day when you specifically request a format just containing year, month and day.